# Setting up diagnostics setting on Blob Storage on storage account - terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to set diagnostics settings on a Azure Storage Account (Blob) .i have configured variables, Main.tf and module inputs. but there are wired Erros and still not getting through.

**variable.tf**

```
variable "diagnostic_settings" {
  type = map(object({
    name                                     = optional(string, null)
    category_group                            = optional(set(string), ["allLogs"])
    metric_categories                        = optional(set(string), ["AllMetrics"])
    log_analytics_destination_type           = optional(string, "Dedicated")
  }))
}
```

**Main.tf**

```
resource "azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting" "blob" {
  for_each = var.diagnostic_settings
  name               = "Example"
  target_resource_id = "${azurerm_storage_account.this.id}/blobServices/default/"
 
  log_analytics_workspace_id = each.value.log_analytics_workspace_id

  dynamic "enabled_log" {
    for_each = var.diagnostic_settings
    

    content {
      category_group = enabled_log.value.category_group
    }


  }
  dynamic "metric" {
for_each = var.diagnostic_settings
   
    content {
      category = metric.value.metric_categories
    }
  }


}
```

**Module Inputs**

```
      diagnostic_settings = {
    blob11 = {
      name                       = "diag"
      log_analytics_workspace_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.this.id
      category_group  = "alllogs"
      #metric_categories          = "AllMetrics"

    }

  }
}
```

ERROR**strong text**

```
│ Error: Invalid value for input variable
│
│   on main.tf line 104, in module "this":
│  104:   diagnostic_settings = {
│  105:     blob11 = {
│  106:       name                       = "diag"
│  107:       log_analytics_workspace_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.this.id
│  108:       category_group  = "alllogs"
│  109:       #metric_categories          = "AllMetrics"
│  110:     }
│  111:   }
│
│ The given value is not suitable for module.this.var.diagnostic_settings declared at ../../variables.tf:835,1-31: element
│ "blob11": attribute "category_group": set of string required.
```

Any suggestions on how I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried to Setting up diagnostics setting on Blob Storage on storage account - terraform and I was able to provision the requirement successfully.

The error message suggests that the `category_group` attribute expects a set of strings. However, in your module inputs, you have provided a single string value for `category_group`.

In your `variables.tf` for `diagnostic_settings`, the default values for `category_group` and `metric_categories` are defined as sets. But when you are setting the values in your module, you are using a single string.

**My terraform configuration :**

##### variable.tf

```
variable "diagnostic_settings" {
  description = "Settings for diagnostics"
  type = map(object({
    name                           = string
    log_analytics_workspace_id     = string
    category_group                 = set(string)
    metric_categories              = set(string)
    log_analytics_destination_type = optional(string)
  }))
}
```

##### main.tf

```
    provider "azurerm" {
        features {}
  }


variable "resource_group_name" {
  description = "Name of the resource group"
  type        = string
}

variable "location" {
  description = "Azure location for the resources"
  type        = string
}

resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "this" {
  name                = "exvksb-workspace"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  sku                 = "PerGB2018"
  retention_in_days   = 30
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "this" {
  name                     = "myvksbstorageaccount"
  resource_group_name      = var.resource_group_name
  location                 = var.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}



resource "azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting" "blob" {
  for_each = var.diagnostic_settings

  name               = each.value.name
  target_resource_id = "${azurerm_storage_account.this.id}/blobServices/default/"
  log_analytics_workspace_id = each.value.log_analytics_workspace_id == "PLACEHOLDER" ? azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.this.id : each.value.log_analytics_workspace_id

  dynamic "enabled_log" {
    for_each = each.value.category_group
    content {
      category_group = enabled_log.value
    }
  }

  dynamic "metric" {
    for_each = each.value.metric_categories
    content {
      category = metric.value
    }
  }
}
```

##### output.tf:

```
output "diagnostic_setting_ids" {
  description = "The IDs of the created diagnostic settings"
  value       = [for ds in azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting.blob : ds.id]
}
```

##### terraform.tfvars:

```
resource_group_name = "v-sakavya"
location            = "East US"

diagnostic_settings = {
  blob11 = {
    name                       = "diagvk-example"
    log_analytics_workspace_id = "PLACEHOLDER"
    category_group             = ["alllogs"]
    metric_categories          = ["AllMetrics"]
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot and it seems to be working... But the issue is, when we are setting up this with multiple storage types like, Queue and table, this will enable on all the storage type. Is there any way to make a condition, only ditect a value on specific variable then process this.  ?

Comment: @csr1985 it is possible to pass all the storage types individually, the same as we have done for blob under **diagnostic_settings**, and then in resource "azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting" add

count = each.value.storage_type == "blob" ? 1 : 0

The diagnostic_settings will be enabled for all the storage types we mentioned under diagnostic_settings.

Comment: @VinayB thanks for the comment. But that will be enable on all storage types. if someone wants to enable this on specific storage type that may not work.

Comment: @csr1985 It can be achieved by adding the modules of storage account types alone you required. Change or remove adding the module if don't want to. However, the query was asked for blob storage type so I tried achieve the same.

Comment: @VinayB . I achieved it by adding multiple variable blocks and resources blocks. Thanks for your support.